# Alert sound in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, stream, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT)**. On click of a button, a beep must **play**. So i used **MediaElement**, but the problem is it **pauses** the **MediaPlayer song**. I even tried to change **AudioCategory /Stream type** but its not helping.

[Stream types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/08/23/media-playback-what-you-need-to-know-about-playing-media-to-make-your-app-shine-in-windows-8.aspx)

Any solution?

```
         private void CreateMediaElements()
      {
          //WINRT:
          MediaElementObject = new MediaElement();
          MediaElementObject.AudioCategory = AudioCategory.Alerts;

          MediaElementObject.IsLooping = false;
          MediaElementObject.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Audio/General/Alerts/ExitCloseAlert_01.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
          MediaElementObject.Height = 0;
          MediaElementObject.Width = 0;

          MediaElementObject.AutoPlay = false;
          LoginPageMainGrid.Children.Add(MediaElementObject);
      }
```

Then on button click :

```
MediaElementObject.Play();
```

Comment: Did the `MediaOpened` or `MediaFailed` events get raised? Maybe there is a problem with the sound file.

Comment: There is no problem in playing the sound. The sound plays very well but it pauses the mediaplayer song. But how to automatically resume mediaplayer song after this ?

Comment: Have you tried using a the PlaySoundAction behavior from Blend?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723982%28v=expression.40%29.aspx